# SQL Server: how to synchronize two tables in different databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, synchronization

I have two databases, A and B. Database A has 3 tables T1, T2 and T3. Those three tables are also contained in database B. Each time there is an update/delete/new record in those three tables in database A I would need to synchronize that with those three tables in database B. How can I do that?

Also, T1, T2, T3 will not be changed in database B. They will only be for reading. So, I only need to update them if there were changes in database A.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187768.aspx) and [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms189799.aspx) to Update the table in Database B if the data is been changed in DatabaseA

```
DECLARE @ID int,@CONTEXT_INFO varbinary(128)

SET @ID = 10
SET @CONTEXT_INFO =cast('ID='+CONVERT(varchar(10),@ID)
+REPLICATE(' ',128) as varbinary(128))
SET CONTEXT_INFO @CONTEXT_INFO

--do Update / Delete of DatabaseA that will fire the trigger

SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x0
```

here is the portion of the trigger to retrieve the value:

```
Create Trigger UpdDel
on TableA --TableA of DatabaseA
Instead of Update,Delete
as
Begin
Begin Try

DECLARE @ID     int
       ,@sCONTEXT_INFO  varchar(128)
SELECT @sCONTEXT_INFO=CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS VARCHAR) 
FROM master.dbo.SYSPROCESSES WHERE SPID=@@SPID

IF Substring(RTRIM(@sCONTEXT_INFO),1,LEN(RTRIM(@sCONTEXT_INFO))) like '%ID%'
BEGIN
    SET @ID=Substring(RTRIM(@sCONTEXT_INFO),LEN(RTRIM(@sCONTEXT_INFO)),1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('ID was not specified',16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    RETURN
END
 Insert into DatabaseB.dbo.TableA(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
 Select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from DatabaseA.dbo.TableA where ID=@ID

/* Do Your Action for DatabaseA table here */ 

End Try
Begin Catch
Declare @ErrMsg Nvarchar(max),@Errseverity int
Set @ErrMsg=ERROR_MESSAGE()
Set @Errseverity=ERROR_SEVERITY()

Raiserror(@ErrMsg,@Errseverity,1)

End Catch
End
```

The Above Trigger is for only one Table  create Triggers like above for other Tables also

Comment: No problem Glad to help If it suits and it solves Your Problem Accept it as Answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this Link
It is possible to synchronize a model in MySQL Workbench with a live database
    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html

Comment: Question is for ms SQL